# Netbeans - Starting of Tomcat failed

Tags: java, netbeans, tomcat7

I am trying to run Tomcat 7 from Netbeans 8.1 but getting the following output
on the server console.

```
    java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4: Unable to create [/usr/share/tomcat7/logs]
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4: Unable to create [/usr/share/tomcat7/logs]
May 20, 2016 8:34:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 20, 2016 8:34:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 20, 2016 8:34:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 20, 2016 8:34:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 20, 2016 8:34:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 20, 2016 8:34:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:398)
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have configured NetBeans to use the system tomcat instance which fails because NetBeans doesn't and shouldn't have permissions to write to `/usr/share/...` (i.e. don't do what you've been told in (the) other answer(s)).

Instead configure NetBeans to use a tomcat instance in your home directory, e.g. by downloading a zip from their download site, extracting it and let NetBeans find it in the corresponding server setup (suppose you're looking for a Java Web server).

Answer (score -1):

You have to try `chown -R /usr/share/tomcat7/logs` to get the current userID(have access to create the logs directory in tomcat7. It seems the userID that you are using to start NetBeans doesn't have that permission.

Comment: How to change User permission?

Comment: you have to use chown and chmod command to do that. please go thru the man pages or google it.

Comment: Don't do that. Never break your system permission. Damage can be unlimited! See a more convenient answer below.

Comment: Note that it's also bad idea to start NetBeans as user with write permissions for `/usr/share/...` - your answer reads like you might suggest that as well.